Render in PDF via Rmarkdown a table with conditional colouring
I have a table in R with 4 columns.1st column names with John Helen and George. 2nd column name pizza with values 0.7, 0.5, 0.33.3rd column name pasta with values 0.4,0.7,0.2. 4th column name sweet with values 0.9, 0.3, 0.2.
df <- data.frame(
  Name = c("John", "Helen", "George"),
  Pizza = c(0.7, 0.5, 0.33),
  Pasta = c(0.4, 0.7, 0.2),
  Sweet = c(0.9, 0.3, 0.2)
)

print(df)

Now I want to color each cell according to 3) criteria: if value >=0.7 then color it green, if the cell value is <= 0.3 and >= 0.15 yellow and otherwise white.
library(formattable)


rules <- formatter(
  "span",
  style = x ~ style(
    color = ifelse(x >= 0.7, "green", ifelse(x <= 0.3 & x >= 0.15, "yellow", "white"))
  )
)


formattable_df <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) as.character(rules(x))))


print(formattable_df)

Now I want to put them all in a rmarkdown file to render a PDF latex style preferably latex table but to keep the conditional colouring in the resulting PDF file.How can I do it?

Not an answer, but I'm assuming that by "color each cell", you mean changing the background color of the table cell. Currently, your formatter() function results in <span style="color: green">, which will only end up changing the color of the text. Change "span" to ""td" and color to background-color (escaped with back ticks!). This results in <td style="background-color: green">, for example.

@cristian-vargas can you work a solution ? I would appreciate it.As well as your comment

I like to do this by creating a function which formats the data appropriately using kableExtra::cell_spec():
set_background <- function(x, color = "white", format = "latex") {
    kableExtra::cell_spec(x, format = format, background = color)
}

You can then apply this to the relevant columns of your data using dplyr::across():
library(dplyr)
df |>
    mutate(
        across(Pizza:Sweet, \(x)
            case_when(
                x > 0.7 ~ set_background(x, "green"),
                x >= 0.15 & x <= 0.3 ~ set_background(x, "yellow"),
                TRUE ~ set_background(x)
            )
        )
    ) |>
    kableExtra::kbl(format="latex", booktabs=TRUE, escape=FALSE)

Make sure that your rmarkdown yaml header contains the appropriate packages:
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{booktabs}
  - \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
---

Output:


awesome.But I have one question out of curiosity: if I had to render to html changing format="latex" to format="html" does not work.Why ?

It should work - note you need to change format = "html" in both the calls to kbl() and set_background() (and obviously change the yaml header as well)
